# How to display locality data response in UI using inner html and if locality value is " "(Empty) we need to display Select as output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Api response is given below

```
[
 {
        "productId": 928,
        "hotelId": 0,
        "productName": "Loc 5",
        "country": "India",
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "locality": "",
        "availableRooms": 0,
        "availableRateplans": 0,
        "status": false,
        "hexStatus": false,
        "additionalProperties": {}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let response = JSON.parse(*YourResponse*).locality;
if(response === ""){
    response = "SELECT";
}
element.innerHTML +=  response;
```

You can also use ternary operator in place of if.